# Using both provider and injection token in ionic creates duplicate instance

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, dependency-injection, ionic3, abstract-factory

I have an interface for my service and an injection token for it:

```
export const AUTH_PROVIDER_IT = new InjectionToken<AuthProvider>('auth')
export interface AuthProvider {
  login(IAuthLoginData): Promise<void>
  logout()
  register(IAuthRegistrationData): Promise<void>
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    ...
    {provide: AUTH_PROVIDER_IT, useClass: CognitoAuthProvider},
  ]
})
```

and I use it in my login page:

```
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, ...
              @Inject(AUTH_PROVIDER_IT) public auth: AuthProvider) {
  }
...
}
```

It all works fine....

But now I have a service which needs the *concrete class*:

```
@Injectable()
export class CognitoProfileProvider implements ProfileProvider {
  constructor(private cognitoAuth: CognitoAuthProvider) {

  }
}
```

So I do this:

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    ...
    CognitoAuthProvider, <--- HERE
    {provide: AUTH_PROVIDER_IT, useClass: CognitoAuthProvider},
    {provide: PROFILE_PROVIDER_IT, useClass: CognitoProfileProvider} <-- AND HERE
  ]
})
```

But when I try to read from `CognitoAuthProvider` in my `CognitoProfileProvider` I realise it is a new instance...

Why am I getting a different instance for the same provider? Is this the expected behaviour?

> Note: I have tested injecting only the concrete provider and it does work, but I want to use the interface.

Maybe I'm handling this wrong, how should I model a parallel inheritance hierarchy with dependency injection? Basically an `abstract` factory pattern, is that possible here?

I want to be able to use (CognitoAuthProvider, CognitoProfileProvider) or (SomeOtherAuthProvider, SomeOtherProfileProvider) in place of my interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

When using both the token and the class itself you must use `useExisting` rather than `useClass` as detailed [here](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#aliased-class-providers)

```
  providers: [
    ...
    CognitoAuthProvider,
    {provide: AUTH_PROVIDER_IT, useExisting: CognitoAuthProvider},
    {provide: PROFILE_PROVIDER_IT, useClass: CognitoProfileProvider}
  ]
```